# Flutter test for bloc event

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, bloc

i have an event bloc
I want to do a test in this event file
but these props are not covered, how do you make them testable?

[image]

here is my code :

```
test('Validate ChangeTabEvent equality', () {
expect(const ChangeTabEvent('category'),
    equals(const ChangeTabEvent('category')));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I understand you correctly. You want to test `props`? Not needed, this is a object used by Equatable, it only lists all variables included in this class.

However, if you want to check if all variables are in `params` included, you can check this according to the following:

```dart
class Person extends Equatable {  // example
  const Person(this.name);
  final String name;

@override
  List<object?>get props => []
}

...

final Person bob = Person("Bob");

test('Validate ChangeTabEvent equality', () {
  expect(bob, equals(Person("Bob"));
});
```

fails, because you have not `name` in `params`

Answer (score 1):

You can add an expect to check the props if the values are as to what value/s you are expecting.

One solution to cover those lines would be:

```
test('Validate ChangeTabEvent equality', () {
// Add these lines
const event = ChangeTabEvent('category');
expect(event.props, ['category']);


expect(const ChangeTabEvent('category'),
    equals(const ChangeTabEvent('category')));
});
```